# Cannot use google authentication api library in background script in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, authentication, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to access an endpoints API from the background script of my chrome extension. I am loading the library (`platform.js`) which I have included as a `web_accessible_resource` in my `manifest.json`.

Basically, I fetch the body of the platform.js file and eval its content to create the `gapi` object.

The code is something like this:

```
$.get(chrome.extension.getURL('/res/lib/js/platform.js'), function(data) {
    eval(data); // To create gapi object
    console.log(gapi);

    if(typeof gapi !== 'undefined'){
        // I should have a auth property in gapi now, but there isnt any
        gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: client_id, scope: scopes, immediate:true}, 
         function(token){})
     }); 
   }
   });
```

My problem is that the gapi object gets created, but has no property called auth. 
The line `gapi.auth.authorize...` needs to be called to authenticate with Google APIs.

I tried using `gapi.load('auth', function(){})` too, but it did not help.

When I load the platform.js in a script tag inside a normal HTML file, it has the 'auth' property by default. I dont have to load it.

Can anyone tell me if there is a solution?

Or, whats the best way to authenticate with Google APIs from a chrome extension without using chrome.identity?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity

Comment: @DanielHerr , I want to use a separate client_id to access my API, from what is present in my manifest.json. Using gapi seems to be the only way.

Comment: Not much clear about what you want, so your question is how to load `platform.js` in background page?

Comment: @HaibaraAi I am able to load the platform.js file, a `gapi` object is created, but `gapi.auth` is what I want.

Comment: @HaibaraAi, when I load the platform.js with a <script> tag inside a normal HTML page, the gapi object is created with the auth property. I am wondering why it doesnt happen when I do it in a chrome extension.

Comment: @HaibaraAi alternatively, i would prefer an answer to: whats the best way to authenticate with Google APIs from a chrome extension without using chrome.identity?

Comment: @trans1st0r, just include `platform.js` as a <script> tag in background.html, isn't it a good way?